# Openshift Origin-rhc app create tomcat7 error - Failed to execute: : 'control start'

Tags: tomcat, openshift-origin

After installing JBoss EWS 2.0 cartridge, app create command leads to error shown below. Openshift Origin is installed on my virtual box centos 6.5 environment. Any help is much appreciated.

rhc app create MyJava7 tomcat7 --trace

Using jbossews-2.0 (Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)) for 'tomcat7'

Application Options

Domain:     mydomain
Cartridges: jbossews-2.0
Gear Size:  default
Scaling:    no

Creating application 'MyJava7' ...
Starting jbossews cartridge
jbossews process failed to start
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/client.rb:737:in `handle_error!': Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/544c1df34fe5a091c8000153/jbossews (RHC::Rest::ValidationException)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/client.rb:394:in`request'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/client.rb:376:in `attempt'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/client.rb:375:in`each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/client.rb:375:in `attempt'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/client.rb:382:in`request'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/base.rb:30:in `rest_method'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/rest/domain.rb:67:in`add_application'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/commands/app.rb:576:in `create_app'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/commands/app.rb:142:in`create'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:190:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:190:in`section'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/highline_extensions.rb:204:in `paragraph'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:293:in`send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/helpers.rb:293:in `paragraph'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/commands/app.rb:138:in`create'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in `send'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in`execute'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `to_commander'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in`call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in`run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/runner.rb:383:in `run_active_command'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:100:in`run!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.0.3/lib/commander/delegates.rb:7:in `run!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in`start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.26.9.1/bin/rhc:20
        from /usr/bin/rhc:19:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/rhc:19

I am getting similar errors while creating Python and Ruby apps.

Answer (score 0):

I've digged all the day about the issue, and it seems that installation of Tomcat/Jboss under CentOS is just broken. The use of alternative repositories (EPEL) to get the required packages still miss something.
I've also found several bug report into the [Openshift tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1016003), but you know, without subscription you are on your own. Openshift has confirmed the bug, as you can read on the comments of the tracker, but fix is still missing.

So, short of options, i've ended to code [my own openshift cartridge](https://github.com/quivalen/openshift-tomcat7-cartridge) to support Tomcat7 (no Jboss support). I don't know if i'm going to the right direction, but at least i can deploy and run something. I hope it helps, feel free to fork and contribute.